# TypeScript Object is possibly 'undefined' despite guard when using Enum as object key

Tags: typescript

I've encountered a problem with TypeScript types and tried to create a focused code sample to elaborate:

Here's a [link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QN4Cgq6gcgCUBRAEXygF4DlgATfAGhz3wCEAZAVWIuvwBGCMMCZYAvliyhIUAMpgB8JGkwtc%20AAoBJAHIBpPgQAOASxABrMXgIwAmgEFdR-AGMAngEMQYyVgAu7sbAUKSe-p4Cnqgh1Ng2ANoWwO5Q5rCIKKgAugD8AFxqNonJqekKSploeYXgEALAyOpQkn6uCNHo2iAAZnBFeK5VhcpZzaiKo8iFFVOozUMgqP7IYK7%20KAAUQyojVaiMUBOVKqgzk-sAlAPFUP4AFqaoAHQ7KFRQb023uA9Pz8cph9Aftmq0pAB6CFQAAqxDkMLkWChlFRaMoUkWyygdAEhTCESiMQ%20GD8PTAIHWpjgICgnjodBhcAJkWiwDkEX8plcm1MhW6fWu8TwuIS%20FoDGyUFyuTi4h%20UChUAAPABaVVQADmYE8yDodM1nnM2IpdGAPXM9GaovF9Hw2TFZks9ulsqgAAZFdC1Rrtbr9Z5Dcb-FBTebLXRrQIxRL7Y7zFYpQBqJM2JU%20qAWkDACRScmUrk0ukMpksonsznc4h1Xn83pwIVRhJzZ4kUhSmVyhUK9PqrU6vUGo1LENhrNWmyiltth2zfbPHQGDtuz29jUAAyn85n66gAHkBAArYDrNLoYxwVCoUxCVL4McR-DPJvTsizi6nBd6fTJ1N4Nf7keJ4hk8UAXleN4IHeD7Zgwz5khSVJFvSjLMuErIxBy4RVnUMLINyyR0LWUACg2NyfDS2KuB8r6kAslEhoCHxzp%20i76E2rjLl2xQAX6g6BsOJogGa46RpO0acQkgJcR6Xoqn2fEBkGI6hsJ4awRxDrSVAKZpt6fbjgAhLmWD5khtIoaW6HlsRpGNnpUAAOIDkpgmjmpomhteICalA4AIAgTz3HSEGaiAECgP4TamK8VQyaS3Y2NFsUqA6MUgqlrrUKu%20kbqKMVfNku4Hsep6geB163gQMF2s%204kJAVcUNQCH4oL%20DkZiVwFnmBl6VVB1UeY%208F5ohhYWSWaGEmyeEEfQtn1vZgwMZ8HyNSo9EqUx1Dpa13wihJ8XyoluCaVJkwyTl8l5YdxVAWV559ZB0FDbBT5ndpun-rlgGlSBj0QVV96vbVJlmeNxaoWWbIAEwLYK5FKrN9B3P0ilDsGqkiRGXnmL53hpD0RycsAEUgFFNimETmz5SlbVCidPzNPV61tc1GVtVlskAZu0as8gRW-d15VPUDNVwczB3NYV7N7e133XULD29YDA3A9jb11Xg4JAA)

Lets say I have these types and class:

```
enum Colors {
    'RED' = 'red',
    'BLUE' = 'blue',
}

enum SubColors {
    'PINK' = 'pink',
    'CYAN' = 'cyan',
}

type Database = {
    [key in Colors]?: {
        [key in SubColors]?: number
    }
}

class Info {
    color: Colors
    subColor: SubColors
    constructor(color: Colors, subColors: SubColors) {
        this.color = color
        this.subColor = subColors
    }
}
```

I created an add function to add items to db based on the info in Info instances:

```
const db: Database = {}

function addToDatabase(i: Info) {
    // Guard against undefined using nullish assignment
    db[i.color] ??= {}             
    db[i.color][i.subColor] ??= 0 // <-- `db[i.color]` Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    db[i.color][i.subColor] ++    // <-- Object is possibly 'undefined'.
}
```

TypeScript complains that `db[i.color]` is possibly 'undefined' despite my guard!

Please see the [link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QN4Cgq6gcgCUBRAEXygF4DlgATfAGhz3wCEAZAVWIuvwBGCMMCZYAvliyhIUAMpgB8JGkwtc%20AAoBJAHIBpPgQAOASxABrMXgIwAmgEFdR-AGMAngEMQYyVgAu7sbAUKSe-p4Cnqgh1Ng2ANoWwO5Q5rCIKKgAugD8AFxqNonJqekKSploeYXgEALAyOpQkn6uCNHo2iAAZnBFeK5VhcpZzaiKo8iFFVOozUMgqP7IYK7%20KAAUQyojVaiMUBOVKqgzk-sAlAPFUP4AFqaoAHQ7KFRQb023uA9Pz8cph9Aftmq0pAB6CFQAAqxDkMLkWChlFRaMoUkWyygdAEhTCESiMQ%20GD8PTAIHWpjgICgnjodBhcAJkWiwDkEX8plcm1MhW6fWu8TwuIS%20FoDGyUFyuTi4h%20UChUAAPABaVVQADmYE8yDodM1nnM2IpdGAPXM9GaovF9Hw2TFZks9ulsqgAAZFdC1Rrtbr9Z5Dcb-FBTebLXRrQIxRL7Y7zFYpQBqJM2JU%20qAWkDACRScmUrk0ukMpksonsznc4h1Xn83pwIVRhJzZ4kUhSmVyhUK9PqrU6vUGo1LENhrNWmyiltth2zfbPHQGDtuz29jUAAyn85n66gAHkBAArYDrNLoYxwVCoUxCVL4McR-DPJvTsizi6nBd6fTJ1N4Nf7keJ4hk8UAXleN4IHeD7Zgwz5khSVJFvSjLMuErIxBy4RVnUMLINyyR0LWUACg2NyfDS2KuB8r6kAslEhoCHxzp%20i76E2rjLl2xQAX6g6BsOJogGa46RpO0acQkgJcR6Xoqn2fEBkGI6hsJ4awRxDrSVAKZpt6fbjgAhLmWD5khtIoaW6HlsRpGNnpUAAOIDkpgmjmpomhteICalA4AIAgTz3HSEGaiAECgP4TamK8VQyaS3Y2NFsUqA6MUgqlrrUKu%20kbqKMVfNku4Hsep6geB163gQMF2s%204kJAVcUNQCH4oL%20DkZiVwFnmBl6VVB1UeY%208F5ohhYWSWaGEmyeEEfQtn1vZgwMZ8HyNSo9EqUx1Dpa13wihJ8XyoluCaVJkwyTl8l5YdxVAWV559ZB0FDbBT5ndpun-rlgGlSBj0QVV96vbVJlmeNxaoWWbIAEwLYK5FKrN9B3P0ilDsGqkiRGXnmL53hpD0RycsAEUgFFNimETmz5SlbVCidPzNPV61tc1GVtVlskAZu0as8gRW-d15VPUDNVwczB3NYV7N7e133XULD29YDA3A9jb11Xg4JAA) to see different things I tried to narrow down the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different solutions I was able to get rid of the error using two intermediate variables (`x` and `count` below):

```
function addToDatabase(i: Info) {
    const x = db[i.color] ?? {}   
    x[i.subColor] ??= 0
    const count = x[i.subColor] ?? 0
    x[i.subColor] = count + 1
    db[i.color] = x   
}
```

instead of:

```
function addToDatabase(i: Info) {
    db[i.color] ??= {}             
    db[i.color][i.subColor] ??= 0 
    db[i.color][i.subColor] ++  
}
```

I think the code is identical to the previous code in terms of logical flow and I don't know *how* this solves the problem, but it worked!

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QN4Cgq6gcgCUBRAEXygF4DlgATfAGhz3wCEAZAVWIuvwBGCMMCZYAvliyhIUAMpgB8JGkwtc%20AAoBJAHIBpPgQAOASxABrMXgIwAmgEFdR-AGMAngEMQYyVgAu7sbAUKSe-p4Cnqgh1Ng2ANoWwO5Q5rCIKKgAugD8AFxqNonJqekKSploeYXgEALAyOpQkn6uCNHo2iAAZnBFeK5VhcpZzaiKo8iFFVOozUMgqP7IYK7%20KAAUQyojVaiMUBOVKqgzk-sAlAPFUP4AFqaoAHQ7KFRQb023uA9Pz8cph9Aftmq0pAB6CFQAAqxDkMLkWChlFRaMoUkWyygdAEhTCESiMQ%20GD8PTAIHWpjgICgnjodBhcAJkWiwE2pkK3T613igxp2IAHh9cQlTK8qtkoLlcphxHhmoKxQCLiopTLqAAGBYC-yfOAUvXUJXikFq6Wy7U2E0qk4oKXUIaGqAAaigAEZmqLxV8HVBhbgJJjdWkPiBgAB3KDcuCbObPEikQ6zfbPHQGS5SemM5nhVkxDmZ7NMllE9mmTNYH1VD7xzg8Ku2oHUFOnZ72JxYYu5wlswvBpaIYDPJAAc02uMuQA)

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure typescript that it won't be undefined with something like this

```
    db[i.color]![i.subColor] ??= 0 
    db[i.color]![i.subColor]! ++
```

Comment: But do this only if you are 100% sure that object will be defined.

Comment: Thanks, but if I do this, I will totally lose the type checking, I'm curious why TS is unable to verify the properties and even doesn't honor my guards!

Comment: I guess the problem is with the definition of the Database type, you defined both properties to be optional, so I guess it makes sense for TS to think that they can be undefined.

Comment: Yes any of the items may be undefined at first, but after `db[i.color] ??= {}` it should be defined  obviously